# When executing sed from java from ProcessBuilder getting : sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Tags: java, sed

i run this command from java in linux :

```
sed -i.bak 's/'1111'/'22222'/' /home/my/test/page.html
```

getting this error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

when executing from java from ProcessBuilder
like this :

```
String s = "'s/'1111'/'22222'/'"

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("sed","-i.bak",s,"/home/my/test/page.html);
```

when running from pure linux console it is working just fine , only from java it gives me this error ..
any idea?

Comment: I think `String s = "\"s/'1111'/'22222'/\"";` would be better. Use `sed -i.bak "s/'1111'/'22222'/" file`

Comment: I think a more appropriate option if possible would be to store the sed command inside its own file. The content of the file would be `s/'1111'/'22222'/` and `sed` would be executed with the additional parameter `-f /path/to/the/script.sed`. There would be no need to interchange quotes or escape them. I don't remember whether ProcessBuilder honour shebangs, but if it does it could further simplify the invocation from Java

Comment: this still give me the same error:
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: String old ="1111"
String newV="22222"
 String[] command={"sed", "-i.bak", "'s/"+old+"/"+newV+"/g'", "/home/my/test/page.html"};

Still give the same error .. what im missing here ...

@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: String old ="1111" String newV="22222" 
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I think you lost single quotes. Try `String[] command={"sed", "-i.bak", "\"s/'"+old+"'/'"+newV+"'/g\"", "/home/my/test/page.html"};`

Comment: i also try with the single quotes and its the same error from java 
the wired thing that in pure linux sed its working fine ...
@WiktorStribiżew

also working in windows cygwin / mingw32